# Webscrape a table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the tables (and then the tr and td contents) with requests and BeautifulSoup from this link: https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/PHI/2022/lineups/ , but I get no results.

I tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/PHI/2022/lineups/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser') 

tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

However the result of tables is [].

Comment: Have you looked at view-source:https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/PHI/2022/lineups/ ? Notice anything?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Now I realize there are no tables in the source. But when i click inspect element, there are. Are they loaded dynamically with javascript? What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tables are placed in the comments, so you have to adjust the response text:

```
page = page.text.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/PHI/2022/lineups/"
page = requests.get(url)
page = page.text.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 

tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

---

Just in addition as mentioned also by @chitown88 there is an option with `beautifulsoup` method of `Comment`, to find all comments in HTML. Be aware you have to transform the strings into `bs4` again:

```
soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and '<table' in text))
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/PHI/2022/lineups/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser') 

soupTables = BeautifulSoup(''.join(soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and '<table' in text)))
soupTables.find_all('table')
```

Comment: ah man. So simple yet I completely didn't think of just simply doing this! Any time I parsed the reference.com site, I pulled out the Comments using bs4's method of `Comments`. But geez, this is so much easier to do! Thanks for posting this!