# BeautifulSoup not working when trying to Scrape HTML table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

When I try to scrape any of the below html elements I get nothing. However, if I try to scrape anything outside of the table It works perfectly fine. I am very confused on why this is happening. I thought perhaps the data was being loaded by JavaScript so I tried using selenium but still same issue it did not scrape any data. Am I missing something Is there some other way I am supposed to scrape data out of a html table?

```
    # Here we will grabe the 2020 seasson stats
jz_2020_raw_stats = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/UTA/2020.html').text
jz_2020_soup_stats = BeautifulSoup(jz_2020_raw_stats,'html.parser')
jz_2020_soup_stats.prettify()

    # Extract the values of the columns we need
    pts = jz_2020_soup_stats.select("#team_and_opponent_sh > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span")[0].text
    print(pts)
    fg_pct = jz_2020_soup_stats.select("#team_and_opponent > tbody:nth-child(4) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6)")[0].text
    print(fg_pct)
    three_pct = jz_2020_soup_stats.select("#team_and_opponent > tbody:nth-child(4) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(9)")[0].text
    tov = jz_2020_soup_stats.select("#team_and_opponent > tbody:nth-child(4) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(22)")[0].text
    ft_pct = jz_2020_soup_stats.select("#team_and_opponent > tbody:nth-child(4) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(15)")[0].text
    
    
    # Print the values
    print('PTS:', pts)
    print('FG%:', fg_pct)
    print('3P%:', three_pct)
    print('TOV:', tov)
    print('FT%:', ft_pct)
```

**Code that ended up working for me:**

```
page = requests.get(jz_2020_url)
page = page.text.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 

table_html = str(soup.find("table", {"id": "team_and_opponent"}))
df = pd.read_html(table_html)[0]

print(df)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Check the part with the comments [Webscrape a table with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615184/webscrape-a-table-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+basketball-reference.com

Comment: @HedgeHog This helped me pull all of the tables out of the HTML but for some reason, I am still unable to retrieve the specific table I am looking for. This is so strange to me because I can print out all of those tables and do ctrl + f and find the specific table I am looking for with no problem, but for some reason, beautiful soup can not.

Comment: @HedgeHog I was able to modify the code a little bit and it ended up working for me (Made the changes above). Cheers!